# How to keep values with same sign in r

Tags: r

I have a data frame like below; Rows are protein IDs and `a` is `experiment 1` and `b` is `experiment 2` that we expect proteins show the same expression values in both experiments however the sign of expression always in not in agreement as heatmap shows that

```
> head(a[,c(1,3)])
            a                              b
A0JLT2      0.29                          0.2
A8MXV4     -1.25                         -0.6
O00194     -2.21                          0.9
O00462      0.68                         -0.6
O00505      1.05                         -0.6
O00560      0.43                         -0.2
>
```

I want to keep only proteins with the `same sign of value (- or +)` in both columns but I don't know how to do that

[image]

Any help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one way -

```
a[sign(a$a) == sign(a$b), ]
```

`sign()` returns the sign of an element.

```
sign(-1.25)
[1] -1

sign(-0.6)
[1] -1

sign(0.29)
[1] 1
```